# how to process the result when using mongo nodejs require('file.js') module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am building an application in nodejs + express + mongodb + ejs.

For this question: I have 2 files (server.js + db.js) All mongo related stuff I put in that separate file (db.js), so that I can do all database queries there.
The problem: result returns a query object, and I dont know how I can use that in an iteration (to list the resulting docs), which I sent to ejs. When I do console.log(result.length) is shows "undefined".

Any thoughts?

/* server.js: */

```
let db = require("./db.js");
app1.get("/page", function (req, res) {
    let result= db.getPLayers(); // console.log(result); ==> query object, see below => Q
    let qty = result.length; // console.log(qty); ==> undefined
    res.render('adm', { playersFound: result}); // sent to render result via ejs
}
```

/* db.js */

```
module.exports.getPLayers = function() {
    return Player.find({});
}
```

// => Q this is the query object that I get as result:

```
> Query {   _mongooseOptions: {},   _transforms: [],   _hooks: Kareem {
> _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },   _executionCount: 0,   mongooseCollection: 
NativeCollection {
>     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
>     Promise: [Function: Promise],
>     _closed: false,
>     opts: { .... and lots more
>
```

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj That's irrelevant here. The problem is that `.find()` is asynchronous. According to [`.find()`'s API docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), you can get the result by either passing a callback to it, or by using it as a _Promise_ with either async/await or  `.then()`.

Comment: @himanshu : no, same result

Comment: module.exports.getPLayers = function(){
   Player.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        console.log("docs:"+docs);
        return docs; // this does list the items, but....
    });
}

// but in server.js ...

app1.get("/adm", function (req, res) {
let result= db.getPLayers();  // undefined 
}

Comment: @cbr can you explain how to implement that?

Comment: What library do you use to work with MongoDB? Do you use [`mongodb`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)(The official driver) or [`mongoose`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose)(A higher-level API)?

Comment: @Taoe-Some-Bytes

I use this: const mongoose = require('mongoose');

However, I have the more related node-modules installed, but not sure if all are actually needed in the end, as I have been prototyping:
mongodb
mongodb-core
mongoose

Answer (score 0):

```
// server.js
app1.get("/adm", function (req, res) {
let db = require("./db.js");
let playersList;
let teamsList;    
db.getPLayers().then(function () {        
    playersList = this.docs;
})
    .then(function () {
        db.getTeams().then(function () {                
            teamsList = this.docs;
        })
            .then(function () {                    
                res.render('adm', { playersFound: 
playersList, teamsFound: teamsList });//, teamsFound: dbteamsFound });
            });
    });
});
// db.js
exports.getPLayers = function(){
return Player.find({}, function (err, docs) {    
    this.docs=docs; console.log("==> db exporting getPlayers :"+ 
this.docs.length);  
});
}
exports.getTeams = function(){
return Team.find({}, function (err, docs) {    
     this.docs=docs; console.log("==> db exporting getTeams :"+ 
 this.docs.length);  
 });
 }
```

Comment: I figured it out, with a series of .then (because I need to combine several queries)

Would there be a more elegant solution than this?